# Document IDs - Prefix Not Working

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-id

Can anyone shed some light on why is it that, regardless of what prefix I set on a site collection's Document IDs (and, of course, I check the "Reset all Document IDs in this Site Collection to begin with these characters." box) - the document IDs will continue to have the ugly randomized ID prefix that SharePoint sets by default?

Basically, I go to settings, type in the prefix I want, check the "Reset all Document IDs..." box, hit "OK", wait until SharePoint thinks about it.
Then when I go back in the same screen, I have a randomized value set as prefix, instead of what I set up.

This is happening again and again. Fully reproductibile.

What do I need to do here!?

Comment: There’s no way to know exactly how long SharePoint will take to update prefix of document IDs to existing documents, but it should update within a day. Whether this issue occurs now?

Comment: The IDs ARE being applied, except that they are being applied with the random prefix rather than the one I set. That is quite annoying. Throwing IDs like that on corporate documents is an indication of slopiness - so  we will not be able to use that ID in our documents if we can't make some sense of it. Needless to say - I really want to have this issue solved as the feature is extremely useful.

Answer (score 1):

Opened a case with Microsoft and they acknowledged a bug in their system. No resolution time given :(

Answer (score 0):

After you set prefix in the Document ID settings, did you see "Configuration of the Document ID feature is scheduled to be completed by an automated process"?
[image]
How many files in the site collection? The length of the set prefix process is related to the number of files.

Comment: yes, I did see that. There are really not too many files in there and the process takes a relatively short while (another thing I would like to know is where do I see/set parameters for these processes). 
The point is that whatever I set the prefix to and hit "Reset all...", it is just re-generates them, using a random prefix value.

Comment: These processes work in the back end. I suggest you open a service request with Microsoft to check.